# C# Outlook VSTO - is there anyway to search the global addresslist with partial string / wildcard filter?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, addressbook

I have a VSTO addin and i am trying to display a list of folks in my address list into a form.  I want to search in my global address list but only do a search based on a wildcard character.

I see [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184654%28v=office.14%29.aspx) loops through all of the entries in the address list but i have over 100K entries so i don't want to do a loop so I thought there might be a way to do an upfront filter in the search

I want to search for any person in the address book who's name starts with "ABC" as an example.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually use EWS (Exchange's WCF like web service) as opposed to using VSTO. This way the code can be invoked on almost any environment.

http://vivekiyer.net/2010/07/17/querying-the-global-address-list-gal-via-exchange-web-services-ews/

Comment: this works but i only get back 99 records when i do a search that should return 500 records.  Any ideas?

Comment: @leora sorry. I only know of EWS existence and not how to use it correctly. I have in the past only ever used it to pull a few emails out of exchange for email based automation.

Comment: now worries . .for now just doing it in the loop to get all records. .

Comment: also, this solution is quite slow .. 100 times slower than native outlook . .any suggestions

Comment: sorry...I have no good solutions to it being slow. Apart from the usual caching suggestions...Web is always going to be slow.